# Formatting Dataset results in email

Tags: sql, vb.net, dataset

I have a program that on load will load the dataset with info from a query.  I then send the information in an email.  Everything is working correctly except the output.  The output is wrapped and not in table format.  If I debug the program and paste the "Value" of "Payouts" into a txt document and save it as an html file it is formatted correctly (Shows in table form).  Here is my Code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


        Try
            Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
            Dim mail As New MailMessage()
            Me.Paid_Out_TbTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataDeliveryServiceDataSet.Paid_Out_Tb)
            Dim payouts = _
            <html>
                <body>
                    <table>
                        <tr><th>My First Column Header</th><th>My Second Column Header</th></tr>
                        <%= From paidOut In Me.DataDeliveryServiceDataSet.Paid_Out_Tb.AsEnumerable _
                            Select <tr><td><%= paidOut.Store_Id %></td><td><%= paidOut.Paid_Out_Comment %></td></tr> %>
                    </table>

                </body>
            </html>

            SmtpServer.Credentials = New  _
            Net.NetworkCredential("****", "****")
            SmtpServer.Port = 25
            SmtpServer.Host = "*****"
            mail = New MailMessage()
            mail.From = New MailAddress("*@*.com")
            mail.To.Add("*@*.com")
            mail.Subject = "Test Mail"
            mail.IsBodyHtml = True
            mail.Body = payouts
            SmtpServer.Send(mail)
            MsgBox("mail send")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
End Sub
```

Here what is sent in an email as the body:

My First Column HeaderMy Second Column Header4567OFFICE SUPPLIES4567REIMBUSEMENT FOR SERVICE PER ROB PER INCIDENT REPORT4567REFUND FOR SERVICE INVOICE# ********4567OFFICE SUPPLIES AND GATORADE

As you can see it's just wrapped and not formatted... How can I get the body to be either in TXT format as a table, or in HTML Format as a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CStr(XElement)` function just returns the content of the element. Use:

```
mail.body=payouts.ToString()
```